# "ionic cordova build android" fails to buld apk

Tags: ionic2, cordova-plugins

**I have set all the required environments. To confirm i checked the requirements to build android using command**

```
cordova requirements
```

**which gave the result as below**

```
Requirements check results for android:

Java JDK: installed 1.8.0

Android SDK: installed true

Android target: installed android-26,android-25,android-24,Google
```

Inc.:Google APIs:24,android-23

```
Gradle: installed C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-3.2\bin\gradle
```

**when i tried to build apk using command**

```
ionic cordova build android
```

**am getting as below**

```
> ionic cordova prepare
> cordova prepare
- Running command [12:17:44]  lint finished in 4.70 s
√ Running command - done!

> cordova build android
× Running command - failed!
[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android (exit code 1):


    ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Arunkumar.DESKTOP-59TSCLF\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144
    The system cannot find the path specified.
    Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: I have set the the path of android sdk and java in environment variables too

Answer (score 0):

Previously I had also faced this problem. I solved my problem by this way. I have installed Gradle in C:\Program Files\gradle\gradle-3.3. I set the Gradle path like that

> GRADLE_HOME C:\Program Files\gradle\gradle-3.3
>
> Add Path C:\Program Files\gradle\gradle-3.3\bin

Comment: Am trying reinstalling android studio. once i done with that will try out setting gradle in path

Comment: Thanks for the help @Rahul.
Solved the issue by reinstalling the android studio.